# Zooming on image in picturebox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gdi+, picturebox

What are some ways to adjust zoom distance of an image in a picturebox?

I'm loading an image from file to a picturebox, here's my code...

```
Dim fs As FileStream

OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "JPG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|" & "BMP Files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|" _
    & "TIF Files (*.tif)|*.tif|" & "PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|" & "ALL Files (*.*)|*.*"
OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select an Image File"
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    currentfilename = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    If currentfilename.ToUpper.EndsWith(".JPG") Or _
    currentfilename.ToUpper.EndsWith(".BMP") Or _
    currentfilename.ToUpper.EndsWith(".TIF") Or _
    currentfilename.ToUpper.EndsWith(".PNG") Then
       If Not (Pic.Image Is Nothing) Then
             Pic.Image.Dispose()
             Pic.Image = Nothing
       End If
       fs = New FileStream(currentfilename, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
       Pic.Image = Image.FromStream(fs)
       original = Pic.Image
    End If
End If
```

And then i'm adjusting the zoom distance using this code...

```
If original Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If Not converted Is Nothing Then
    converted.Dispose()
End If
If Not zoomImage Is Nothing Then
    zoomImage.Dispose()
End If

zoomImage = New Bitmap(original, _
            (Convert.ToInt64(original.Width * (ZoomValue) / 100)), _
            (Convert.ToInt64(original.Height * (ZoomValue / 100))))

converted = Graphics.FromImage(zoomImage)

converted.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic

Pic.Image = Nothing
Pic.Image = zoomImage
```

I don't have a proble with this if i'm just using small images but it's using a lot of memory if i have a large image, for example, one image i'm displaying is a 1.5MB TIFF file that has a size of 33000 x 4000. I only want to adjust zoom levels of the image, I don't need anything else like drawing on the image, changing a color of a pixel or any other manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2655391/4291215) which suggests you might want to handle the Paint event of your panel/picturebox

You could do it like so :

```
Private Sub Pic_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Pic.Paint
    Dim newRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, _
        (Convert.ToInt64(original.Width * (ZoomValue / 100))), _
        (Convert.ToInt64(original.Height * (ZoomValue / 100))))
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(u, New Rectangle(0, 0, Pic.Width, Pic.Height), _
                            newRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
End Sub
```